# Subtract shifted vectors in R

Tags: r

Say I have a vector in R:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
```

is there a concise way to create a new vector y that is one less than the size of x where:

```
y <- x[i+1] - x[i]
```

without using a for-loop?

Comment: For dataframes see the related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405552/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`diff(x)`is the obvious answer.

A more basic alternative is `x[-1] - x[-length(x)]` and this can easily be adapted for example to sums or products of consecutive terms

Answer (score 5):

You can use "diff" to get the difference between two consecutive elements in a list,

example :

```
diff(x)
```

may help you.